# spark timestamp conversion fail

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a CSV dataset with the following two columns:

```
scala> df2.select(col("_c1"), col("_c2")).show
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                _c1|                _c2|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-03-11 01:59:59|
|2015-10-24 21:00:00|2015-11-01 01:59:59|
|2017-03-12 02:00:00|2017-03-25 19:59:59|
|2015-10-24 21:00:00|2015-11-01 01:59:59|
|2017-03-12 02:00:00|2017-03-25 19:59:59|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

and I am trying to convert the column to TimestampType:

```
df2.select(unix_timestamp(col("_c1"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType).as("c1"), unix_timestamp(col("_c2"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType).as("c2")).show
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                 c1|                 c2|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-03-11 01:59:59|
|2015-10-24 21:00:00|2015-11-01 01:59:59|
|               null|2017-03-25 19:59:59|
|2015-10-24 21:00:00|2015-11-01 01:59:59|
|               null|2017-03-25 19:59:59|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, I am getting nulls during the conversion. 
Environment info: 
- The local timezone is CDT. 
- Spark version is 2.2.0

The only case I am not getting nulls is when i set the timezone to UTC.

Any suggestions to narrow down the issue?

Comment: what are the datatypes of c1 and c2 columns before casting to timestamp? can you share the schema of df2?

Comment: df2 is generated from a CSV dataset so all columns are of type String. I am trying to cast them

Comment: I tried your code in spark 2.3 and it worked without such error

Comment: I could reproduce it in 2.2.0 with Central Time as the Timezone. It works if you remove unix_timestamp and just use cast. It also works when you submit the entire statement a sql query to spark.sql

Answer (score 1):

**This might not be the complete answer but is explanation about nulls.**

This is working as expected as "null"s are observed when timezone is set to CDT. Please note that CDT timezone observes daylight saving which means "**local time changes at 02:00 local standard time to 03:00 local daylight time on the second Sunday in March**"

In your case "2017-03-12 02:00:00" happens to be second Sunday of March hence the time itself is invalid if timezone is set to CDT. Also will observe nulls if time is in between "2017-03-12 02:00:00" to "2017-03-12 02:59:59"

Reference: 1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone

2] Spark timestamp behavior: https://gist.github.com/squito/f348508ca7903ec2e1a64f4233e7aa70